# Generating Random Numbers

Tags: c, random, numbers

I am using rand() function in C. To limit the range I do rand() % 1e6, so that numbers are between 0 and 1e6. A sample set of numbers generated is following...

5320428
6386236
5536806
7396572
8798055
1095930
9398652

So you can see that numbers are always b/w 1e5 and 1e6. However I want numbers which are randomly distributed, that is they can be 20, 2000, or 2e5 etc..., and which are not likely be b/w 1e5 and 1e6. How can I achieve that sort of distribution in C?

Comment: "So you can see that numbers are always b/w 1e5 and 1e6.": no I cannot.

Comment: You could as well develop a new rand function (of course, you won't call it rand) and perform some statistical math on the function rand. I hate statistics; that's why I'm reluctant to attempt writing it but I'll give it a try.

Comment: The `rand()` function always returns a number between 0 and RAND_MAX which is defined as being at least 32767,  MS compilers this is the case. So I am not sure how you are even getting numbers in the range of 1e5 and 1e6. What compiler are you using and what is the value defined for RAND_MAX?

Comment: For the record, RAND_MAX is 2^31-1 on my recent Linux system.

Comment: @Alexanre and @Chris are both right. It depends on your compiler. When I ran it, I got numbers between 41 and 29358 with a wide distribution. But I still think I'm going to consider defining a new rand function as noted in my previous comment.

Comment: @Chris, I am using the g++ compiler in 64 bit linux.

Answer (score 6):

You appear to have misunderstood the nature of randomness. Small numbers will come out of that distribution, just *not very often*. If your modulus is 1e6, you'd expect to see a number below 2000 only once in every 500 calls or so.

```
int main(void) {
    int n=0, r;
    do { r = rand()%1000000; ++n; } while(r>2000);
    printf("it took %d calls\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

And sure enough:

```
$ ./t
it took 462 calls
```

Now, `rand` is convenient, but it is not a very good source of entropy; the generator is usually only linear congruential (i.e. the randomness is not very good and has a short period). You'd get better randomness from the Mersenne Twister. In either case you need to think carefully about how you're seeding the generator - a system-provided entropy source such as `/dev/urandom` is usually best.

Answer (score 0):

If you need such randomness that numbers with 1,2,,..6 digits will appear with the same probability,
ie you need not linear, but exponential "evenness" don't use simply rand, but something as:

round(10ˆ(rand(6000000)/1000000))